# Conditionally add subgraph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, nodes

I have a set of cypher clauses that I want to apply repeatedly until the graph stops changing. For that, I require that the clauses check, whether they have already run. For example, if I have a clause adding an edge (a:X) --> (b:Y), then that clause should only run, iff (a:X) --> (b:Y)  does not yet exist. I tried to use `MERGE` like so:

Clause 1 (add root node): `CREATE (root:root)`

Clause 2 (add child node): `MERGE (root:root)-[r:some_rel]->(b:child)`

However, when running both clauses, it will produce three nodes. Is there a way, to make the `(root:root)` from Clause 2 be matched to the one from Clause 1?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run these two clauses as separate queries?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running them as a single query, and use the node created from the `CREATE` statement, like this:

```
CREATE (root:root)
MERGE (root)-[r:some_rel]->(b:child)
```

Update, to keep them independent, try this:

Query 1 - `CREATE (root:root)`

Query 2 -

```
MATCH (root:root) 
MERGE (root)-[r:some_rel]->(b:child)
```

Comment: I require them to be independent, though.